# Spring Jackson excluding specific properties during serialization

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson

I have a spring web service that has the controller return Java Objects. I've set my service up to use `@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` so that the response is in Json. To my understanding, Spring uses Jackson to serialize the Java object to Json. I have a class for which I want to create a custom json serializer for. The only reason I want to use a custom serializer is to avoid serializing a specific property of the Object as part of the API response.

For example:

My controller method returns `Foo`. Spring will serialize all the properties as part of the API response. But, I would like to exclude `rawBar`.

```
public final class Foo{
  Bar propBar;
  Bar intermediateBar;
  Bar rawBar;
  FooBar status;
}
```

I've seen examples of using `StdSerializer<T>` to create a custom serializer. But, doing so means I will have to write custom code to serialize the other properties. Is there a way to exclude the specific property? Also, `Foo` is part of a third party library, so making changes to that class is not possible. Is it perhaps possible to create my own serializer for `Foo`, but then use the default serializer to to serialize all the properties except for `rawBar`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be create your own class FooWrapper with attributes you wanted from foo, copy them to fooWrapper and return fooWrapper from your controller.

```
public class FooWrapper {
  Bar propBar;
  Bar intermediateBar;      
  FooBar status;
}

FooWrapper convertFooToFooWrapper(Foo foo) {
  FooWrapper fooWrapper = new FooWrapper ();
  BeanUtils.copyProperties(fooWrapper, foo);
  return fooWrapper ;
}
```

Comment: Foo is part of a third party library, so making changes to that class is not possible

Comment: Try using @JsonIgnore annotation on top of the attribute which needs to be excluded. It is in jackson library.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned by @user12190 easiest is to do :

```
public class Foo {

    Bar intermediateBar;
    Bar rawBar;
    FooBar status;
    Bar propBar;

    public Bar getPropBar() {
        return propBar;
    }

    public void setPropBar(Bar propBar) {
        this.propBar = propBar;
    }

    public Bar getIntermediateBar() {
        return intermediateBar;
    }

    public void setIntermediateBar(Bar intermediateBar) {
        this.intermediateBar = intermediateBar;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Bar getRawBar() {
        return rawBar;
    }

    public void setRawBar(Bar rawBar) {
        this.rawBar = rawBar;
    }

    public FooBar getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(FooBar status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

You will need to include in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```